# Can you add http headers to be sent on a crossdomain fopen call?

Tags: php, http, cross-domain, fopen

I mean, I want to open an image file which is on another website, but they have some sort of server side script which only provides the image in case a certain cookie is set on the browser.

Is it possible for me to make a `fopen` call sending in a cookie header?

Comment: my code is like `fopen("http://www....jpg", "r")` that's about all.

Comment: I hope you aren't trying to avoid systems they have put in place to prevent what you are trying to do. You might just find your solution breaking when they see the logs that reveal your workaround.

Comment: Use `cURL` instead of `fopen`.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yes that's what I'm trying to do. You see it's just this ad-hoc solution for a one time only thing. I need to get exif info out of a batch of pictures on the server. Don't worry though, they are all my pictures, it's just a website I use to upload my photos... They only show when I'm loged in

Comment: If it's a one-time thing, might not a browser user script make this easy?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'll try that. I want to parse this data and store them on a database on my own website. Guess I could just create a server script to receive the data on a GET parameter, and get the actual data through javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can control the HTTP request, including adding cookies, by configuring the HTTP stream context.

Check out this example from the manual: http://php.net/stream-context-create

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

/* Sends an http request to www.example.com
   with additional headers shown above */
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php for all HTTP context options.